# how to get array of objects with the value in the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr = [
  { key:1, value: "test1", data:[1,2] }, 
  { key:2, value: "test2", data:[2] },
  { key:3, value: "test3", data:[1] }
];
let selectedData = 1;
```

How to get the objects where 1 is there in `data` ie the expected output is:

```
resultarray = [
  { key:1, value: "test1", data:[1,2] },
  { key:3, value: "test3", data:[1] }
];
```

Comment: doesn't the second element have ``1`` in ``data`` as well

Comment: no it was not in the element

Comment: Can u explain why the first and last elements were in the expected output then?

Comment: yes i am having data similar to arr i need to filter the data where data has id ie 1 in the array and sorry i will correct the data also please check once again